# Heroku won't recognize my intermediate cert

Tags: ssl

I have two subdomains: `www.snipsalonsoftware.com` and `app.snipsalonsoftware.com`. The `www` subdomain is pointed at a Rackspace Ubuntu server running apache and the `app` subdomain is pointed at Heroku.

I purchased a wildcard cert from Comodo (via DNSimple) and I was able to get it working just fine for the `www` subdomain. I'm having trouble with Heroku, though.

[This blog post](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/09/16/how-to-add-a-dnsimple-ssl-certificate-to-heroku/) seems to match my exact situation. I believe I followed its instructions to the letter but my cert still seems to be improperly configured on Heroku. If I visit `app.snipsalonsoftware.com` on a simulated Android device, I get a security warning. (Some people visiting the site on an Android device say they don't get the warning.)

https://www.digicert.com/help/ says my configuration is fine.

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Android 2.2 and lower won't accept some valid SSL certificates, IIRC.

Comment: Okay, I was using 2.2 to test and I do see that it works on 2.3. I wonder if it's advisable just to make it a "system requirement" to have Android > 2.2.

Comment: [Almost nobody is still using 2.2](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), so ...